# Rails custom error message for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

**user.rb**

```
has_many :friends
accepts_nested_attributes_for :friends
```

**friend.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
validates :name, presence: true
```

Attributes for `friends` are submitted in the `user` form. If the `name` field is blank I get this error:

```
Friends name can't be blank
```

I want to rename "Friends" as something else, maybe "Contacts". Same with "name" - I'd like to rename it as "Title". I've tried the following and many variations but no change:

**en.yml**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user/friend:
        attributes:
          name: "Title"
    errors:
      models:
        user/friend:
          attributes:
            name: "Title"
```

Comment: Just curious if you found a solution to this yet? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      friend: Contact
    attributes:
      friend:
        name: Title
```

see [docs here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

Comment: This changes the field label names in the form, but it remains unchanged in the error message: `Friends name can't be blank`. I'm sorry, I'm still baffled.